# An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to get started using nservicle ebus using some samples from the nservicebus. I am unable to get a simple example to work. Please let me know if I am missing something

An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'.

Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException was unhandled
  Message=Exception occurred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart
  Source=NServiceBus.Host
  StackTrace:
       at Magnum.StateMachine.ExceptionActionDictionary`1.HandleException(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter, Exception exception) in :line 0
       at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
       at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionBase`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
       at Magnum.StateMachine.State`1.RaiseEvent(T instance, BasicEvent`1 eevent, Object value) in :line 0
       at Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachine`1.RaiseEvent(Event raised) in :line 0
       at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 77
       at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 40
       at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControllerProxy.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceControllerProxy.cs:line 47
       at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControllerProxy.Start()
       at Topshelf.Internal.FacadeToIsolatedServiceController`1.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\FacadeToIsolatedServiceController.cs:line 62
       at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceCoordinator.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceCoordinator.cs:line 48
       at Topshelf.Internal.Hosts.ConsoleHost.Run() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\Hosts\ConsoleHost.cs:line 53
       at Topshelf.Internal.Actions.RunAsConsoleAction.Do(IRunConfiguration configuration) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\Actions\RunAsConsoleAction.cs:line 33
       at Topshelf.Runner.Host(IRunConfiguration configuration, String[] args) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Runner.cs:line 70
       at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_8\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 134
  InnerException: 
       Message=Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'.
       Source=NServiceBus.Host
       StackTrace:
            at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_8\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 45
            at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_8\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:line 56
            at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_4(WindowsHost service) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_8\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 97
            at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ControllerDelegates.cs:line 18
            at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1(TService service) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 65
            at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 35
            at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
            at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
       InnerException: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
            Message=An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'.
            Source=NServiceBus.Core
            StackTrace:
                 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
                 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b_*6()
                 at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
                 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringPropertyInjector.InjectProperties(IComponentContext context, Object instance, Boolean overrideSetValues)
                 at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClassd.<PropertiesAutowired>b__c(Object s, ActivatingEventArgs`1 e)
                 at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
                 at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivating(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__6()
                 at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c*_DisplayClass4.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_1(IComponentRegistration cr)
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
                 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
                 at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
                 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
                 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
                 at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Autofac.Internal.ContainerExtensions.ResolveAll(IComponentContext container, Type componentType)
                 at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Autofac.AutofacObjectBuilder.BuildAll(Type typeToBuild)
                 at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.CommonObjectBuilder.<NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IBuilder.BuildAll>d__1`1.MoveNext()
                 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
                 at NServiceBus.Unicast.Config.StartupRunners.<Run>b__4(Object obj, EventArgs ev)
                 at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action startupAction)
                 at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start()
                 at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_8\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 32
            InnerException: System.Net.WebException
                 Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
                 Source=System
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString()
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ExecuteRequest()
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPutIndex(String name, String operationUrl, Boolean overwrite, IndexDefinition definition)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c_*DisplayClass34.b*_33(String operationUrl)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.PutIndex(String name, IndexDefinition definition, Boolean overwrite)
                      at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.PutIndex[TDocument,TReduceResult](String name, IndexDefinitionBuilder`2 indexDef, Boolean overwrite)
                      at NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.Persistence.RavenTimeoutPersistence..ctor(IDocumentStore store)
                 InnerException:

Comment: Looks like the security is botched on Raven.  Did you run the bat file to install it?  Can you get to the Raven console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When i created a new MVC project a default connection string was added.
It appears that Nservicebus sees the presence of that connect string as some kind of indicator to use ravendb for persistence etc..Once I removed it, samples started to work